# what is the best way to read and do some processing on large wav files in python

Tags: python, wav, large-files

This is the code I am using to read a `.wav` file to compute the envelope of the signal. It works really fine, but when i try read some file that are greater than 200MB, it just wouldn't work.

Any help is really apreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
from tkinter import filedialog

# Browse, read the signal and extract signal informations (fs, duration)
filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("""
            Template files""", "*.wav"), ("All files", "*")))

fs, data = read(filename, mmap=True)

T = len(data) / fs        #duration
nsamples = T * fs       #number of samples
time = np.linspace(0, T, nsamples)


# Compute the envelope of the signal
from scipy.signal import hilbert
analytic_signal = hilbert(data)

len_E = len(amplitude_envelope)
t2 = np.linspace(0,T,len_E)

# Plot the signal and its envelope
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(time, data)

plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(t2,amplitude_envelope)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please give some more details. "it just wouldn't work" is't enough to get the full picture.

Comment: What error do you get? Did you try more than one file? Fix the typo in 200 Mgb please

Comment: it doesn't give an error, it just still runnig till the programe is " no longer responding"